# How to create multiple pyramid in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a multiple pyramid program using **Javascript** but I really don't understand from where should I start to create multiple **star pyramid program**.

**Note**: I have to create this using **For Loop**.

**Output I want**:

```
*         *
* *     * *
* * * * * *
```

**Here is my Code:**

```js
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            document.write("*"+ " ")
        }
        for(k=5;k>=1;k=k-2){
          for(m=1;m<=k;m++){
              document.write("*")
          }
 
        }
    
        document.write("<br>")
    }
```

Comment: what was the input to get that output

Comment: I'm new in coding I don't konw how to do this! mybad

Comment: @vaira it's up to you.

Comment: I have to make it using ```for loop```.

Comment: do you just want to create that exact shape or the shope will expand with input

Comment: now it should be exacect shape.

Comment: @jabaa no it is not working.

Comment: but I have to create this using multiple for loops! not like this

Comment: dude this is not what I want I have to create first pyramid then second pyramid with space and at the end third pyramid with stars.

Comment: @jabaa logically you are correct but this is not what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var allowedIndexes = [];
const columnNum = 6
for(var i=0; i<3 ;i++){
    
    allowedIndexes.push(i)
    allowedIndexes.push(columnNum - (i+1))
    for(var j=0;j< columnNum ;j++){
            
        if(allowedIndexes.includes(j)){
            document.write("*&nbsp;")
        }
        else {
            document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")
        }

    }

    document.write("<br>")

}
```

Comment: but I don't want to use arrays or any fucntion?

Answer (score 1):

The following code would draw a double pyramid of N levels, using underscores `(_)` to depict spaces. You may modify the characters used.

```js
const drawPyramid = length => {
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    
    const N = 2*(length - i - 1)
    , blankValues = [...Array(N+1).keys()].slice(1).map(n => n + i)
    
    for (let j = 0; j < 2 * length; j++) {
        if (!blankValues.includes(j)) document.write("* ")
        else document.write("_ ")        
    }
    document.write("<br>")
  }
}

drawPyramid(3)
document.write("<br>")
drawPyramid(4)
document.write("<br>")
drawPyramid(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const writePyramid = (levels, row = 0, level = [], spacers = 0) => {
    if (row === levels) return;
    document.write("<br>")
    if (spacers === 0) spacers = levels + 1;
  
    let stars = new Array(row + 1).fill('*')
  
    level = [...stars, ...new Array(spacers > 1 ? spacers : 0).fill('&nbsp;&nbsp;'), ...stars]

    document.write(level.join(''))
    
    writePyramid(levels, row + 1, level, spacers / 2);
}

writePyramid(3)
```

Comment: but I want to use 3 loops for different work first loop print 1st star pyramid second print space and 3rd print star pyramid? any way

Comment: gotcha, ive updated Lu answer to reflect

Comment: it's not what i want if user enters the 10 value then what shuld I do?

Comment: Then you need a function, this should be a recursion problem so that u can update the values dynamically. It's bad practice to rewrite logic for the same thing with minor changes, use the function. Im reposting my original answer